# Changing the order of sections with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am doing an exercise with responsive layouts and floats. In my layout I have four sections that are displayed side by side using floats. One small section, then a big one, and then two more small sections. For smaller screen sizes, I want the "big" section to move up and be displayed first, taking the full width.

The three small sections should go below the big section, side by side. I can't figure out how to change the order of the sections, so the first small section can be in a row with the other two.
How can I move the big section up (or move down the first small section) with just CSS?

```css
section {
  height: 350px;
  width: 19.4444%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.big {
  width: 41.6666%;
}
```

```html
<section class="small"></section>
<section class="big"></section>
<section class="small"></section>
<section class="small"></section>
```

Comment: Don't use `float` for alinging pupose in 2022. Since 2015 we got Flexbox. Float is for floating an element within a text-block. Flexbox as mentioned before solevs this issue and can use the `order`-property

Comment: Thanks for the input. I know floats are not meant for this but at this point in my learning program I am supposed to play around with them. Seems like my particular problem cannot be solved this way though. Learning Flexbox next.

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap the Sections and apply Flexbox to the wrapping element. Then also apply `flex-wrap: wrap` to the same element.

Use `media queries` to target small screens and change the order of the `.big` element with the `order-property`. Also change the size within the `media queries` accordingly:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 576px) {   
    .flexbox > .big {
      order: -1;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .flexbox > .small {
      width: calc(100% / 3);
    }
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
    
/* original CSS */
section {
  height: 350px;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.big {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <section class="small"></section>
  <section class="big"></section>
  <section class="small"></section>
  <section class="small"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS grid rather than floating the items.

For the wider viewports you could have the columns defined as
`1fr 41.6666% 1fr 1fr`

The fr units divide up remaining free space, in this case into 3 equal sections.

For the narrower viewports you could set the grid to have 3 equal columns and then put the big element into the first row and the rest into the second row.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 41.6666% 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1vw;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 350px;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    height: 700px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .big {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  }
  .small {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="small"></section>
  <section class="big"></section>
  <section class="small"></section>
  <section class="small"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: as container width you should use `auto`  as you currently overflowing. if you take 100vw as width, then no parent is allowed to have a margin or padding. By default, you overflowing because of the default body margin. Instead of using `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` you could also use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` which has the same effect. `grid-column: 1 / span 3` can be shorten to `grid-column: 1 / -1` or `grid-column: span 3`

Comment: The width of course has to be set depending on the use case - I used 100vw just as an example andI set everything to have margin 0 and box-sizing border-box in order to avoid overflowing - I see no (horizontal) overflow. Of course there is vertical overflow because of the setting of height (which again is there just for a demo and of course the eventual setting depends on the actual use case). What system are you seeing overflow on?

Comment: https://imgur.com/B82JAVJ => interesting I see no reason why it overflows, testing on Firefox v102.0

Comment: I found the reason for the horizontal overflow. It is the vertical scrollbar. The scrollbar is not included to the 100vw as it is not part of the container itself. So you really should set the width to `auto` or limit it with `max-width: 100%`